# SQL query email attachment - lots of spurious data in the output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running the following query as a scheduled job and sending the output as a query :

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SQL-Server',
@recipients = 'XXXXX',
@subject = 'Missing Essence File Check',
@query = N'SELECT *   FROM ([omnibus].[dbo].[OmniBus_CLP_Clips] CLP 
inner join [omnibus].[dbo].[OmniBus_CLD_ClipDetails] CLD on CLP.FLE_ID = CLD.FLE_ID) 
inner join [omnibus].[dbo].[OmniBus_FLE_Files] fle on clp.FLE_ID = fle.fle_id
where CLD_user_data  like '%.mov%'
and CLD_user_data  not like '%.m2v%'
and CLD_user_data  not like '%.wav%'
and fle.FLE_file_deleted = 0;',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Missing Essence File Check.txt'
```

When I execute this query in SQL Server Management Studio, the output is a list of 8 digit ID numbers, or the message 'no rows affected'.  When I execute the query as a scheduled job and then email the results using Database Mail, I get all this additional data that I do not want or need.  Why does all this additional info appear in the output?  How do I get rid of it?

```
*FLE_ID      CLP_clip_name                                                    CLP_clip_title                                                                                                                   CLT_ID      CLP_in_point CLP_out_point CLP_duratio
n CLP_duration_frames CLP_tc_format_id CLP_complexity CLP_Locations                                                                                                                                                                                             



rowversion CLP_WorkflowStatus   CLP_XTL                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                CLP_InheritanceEnabled FLE_ID      CLD_vision_duration CLD_audio_duration CLD_prog_start CLD_video_mode CLD_audio_mode CLD_video_trans CLD_audio_trans CLD_wipe_mode CLD_wipe_num CLD_quality CL
D_cache_mode CLD_logo    CLD_gpi     CLD_not_before CLD_not_after CLD_start_date          CLD_end_date            CLD_pdc     CLD_precompile CLD_archive_after CLD_delete_after CLD_suppress_logo CLD_size    CLD_version CLD_mirror  CLD_loop CLD_group_id CLD_
status  CLD_use_caption CLD_use_subtitle CLD_record  CLD_clip_unavailable CLD_cg_command CLD_cg_next_page CLD_cg_version CLD_speed   CLD_split   CLD_flags   CLD_pdc_type CLD_user_data_size CLD_subtitle_file                                                CL
D_cg_seq_flag CLD_source_format CLD_active_region CLD_user_data                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                   FLE_ID      FLE_external_key                                   FLE_sharer_path                                                                                                                  FLE_secondary
_path                                                                                                               DOM_ID      FLE_file_name                                                    FLE_file_title                                                 
FLE_file_cats                                                                                                                                                                                 

FLT_ID      SFT_ID      FLE_creator                      FLE_date_created        FLE_date_accessed       FLE_date_modified       FLE_file_deleted FLE_file_dustbinned FLE_keywords                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              FLE_timestamp FLE_protected FLE_co
ntents FLE_write_date          FLE_Synchronised FLE_unique_key                                                                                                                  
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------ ------------- -----------
- ------------------- ---------------- -------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------ ---------- -------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- ----------- ------------------- ------------------ -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------- --------------- ------------- ------------ ----------- --
------------ ----------- ----------- -------------- ------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- -------------- ----------------- ---------------- ----------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------- ------------ ----
------- --------------- ---------------- ----------- -------------------- -------------- ---------------- -------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------- --
------------- ----------------- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------ ----------- ----------- -------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------- ------------------- -----------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ------------- ------
------ ----------------------- ---------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(0 rows affected)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query begins with `SELECT *` so of course you will get all columns in all the tables in the resultant query. Running the exact same script separately in management studio will not show you anything different.

To solve that problem - just include the columns you are interested in within the select statement.

As for your other issues, see the MSDN page on [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190307.aspx): - I believe you are after the optional parameter `@query_result_header` which specifies that you want the column names in the output - you want to set it to 0 to exlude them.

Although I haven't tried it, I believe using the setting `@exclude_query_output` to 0 will exclude the "(0 rows affected)" message, but also exclude the output of the query you are after, so to just remove that row count message, I'd suggest pre-pending your query with the usual `SET NOCOUNT ON;` if you don't want to include that either.

Comment: Many thanks - this

"As for your other issues, see the MSDN page on sp_send_dbmail: - I believe you are after the optional parameter @query_result_header which specifies that you want the column names in the output - you want to set it to 0 to exlude them"

did the trick for what I wanted.